# ASP event not going to handler method, jumps to page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using visual studio and I bound a method to the "onclick" event of a button. In this event, a Session[] variable is to be set, which is displayed on postback.

However, even though all the code compiles, I'm getting NullReferenceExceptions.

Going through it with the debugger, VS shows me that the method that is supposed to be run is skipped completely and it jumps directly to Page_Load. I've never had this happen before and so I don't know what's causing it. I had VS generate the method and so I expect it to actually go to that method.

EDIT: to clarify, I'm setting a string to a Session[] variable, which will be accessed the moment the page reloads. So, I need to set it before the page reloads. But if it goes to Page_Load, that means the page has already reloaded, no?

EDIT2: some code:

```
<asp:Button ID="registerBtn" Text="Register" runat="server" onclick="registerBtn_Click" />
```

I expect that method named in onclick to be executed, and then the page reloaded. Once the page has been reload, Page_Load kicks in.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have been trying?

Comment: Post-backs always go to `Page_Load` first, then to the handler.  Is it never getting to the handler at all?  Or is it going there after `Page_Load`?

Comment: @David there is an error occuring in page_load because I want to get some data that is only set in the handler. That's why the handler has to happen before the page_load, because the page_load needs that data. This session variable needs to be set *before* postback

Comment: @Koen027: Then you're going to need to re-design how your logic works.  A post-back is a call to the page, which triggers `Page_Load` to run.  The handler runs afterward.  `Page_Load` can't have a dependency on the handler, ASP.NET doesn't work that way.

Comment: @David: wait a minute. Postback is a boolean that is set on page load. Right? Imagine I'm on my page. I enter data and click the button. Once I click that button, I expect the method bound to it to be executed and only after that the page to be reloaded.

Comment: @Koen027 Your expectations have no bearing on how asp.net acutally works. Review the link AVD posted. It clearly lays out the order of events that take place.

Comment: @Koen027: Take a look at the link in AVD's answer below.  What you're looking to do is not how ASP.NET works.  Post-back isn't "a boolean" or anything like that.  It's an HTTP POST request to the page.  Being stateless, the page goes through its full life-cycle on every request.  `Page_Load` fires before event handlers in that life-cycle.  You're trying to make this fit the WinForms model, but it's an entirely different architecture.

Comment: @David: the link is useless to me. I've done this before and this is the first time it's not working. I checked several earlier projects and it's all working there with no difference in the code I can see. In the way I am describing here. Click button, execute code, **then** reload page.

Comment: @Koen027: Can you provide code that demonstrates how you've done this before?  Or some code from your current attempt?  That would help us help you.

Comment: @Koen027: "Click button, execute code, then reload page" - Execute the code on what?  The `Page` class?  The class needs to be constructed and loaded into memory before you can execute any code on it.

Answer (score 4):

Controls event will be handled after the Page_Load event. Take a look at [ASP.NET Page Life cycle event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events).

Comment: but the Page_Load event is executed when the page is loaded again, right? I want the handler to be executed and only then the page to reload. When all I need to set has been executed.

Comment: Page_Load is not the appropriate place to to run your logic. Please review the ASP.Net lifecycle link in the answer.

Comment: @asawyer: Page load happens when the page is reloaded. I want this code to be executed before any new page is sent from the server.

Comment: @Koen027: We can't stress this enough... That's not how ASP.NET works.  The page has to be loaded (not returned to the client yet, but loaded into the call stack on the server) in order to call any code on it.  _Any_ class needs to be constructed before you can use it, `Page` is no exception to this.  When a `Page` class is constructed, it goes through a specific order of events.  That order includes calling `Page_Load` _before_ calling any queued event handlers.  You are trying to do something that ASP.NET doesn't do.

Answer (score 1):

Put your logic in a function, in Page_Load verify if is not a Postback to call your function (if you need) in the EventHandler do what you do and then call the function, so you call your logic after what you do in the handler and not in the page load.